# Tool to check whether all C++ functions throwing exception in one program

Tags: c++, exception, automation

I have a large C++ program. I found that some functions may throw exceptions but others not. If exception happened, the program would crash. So, try-catch is helpful. But there are so many functions. Is there a tool which automatically list all the functions which may throw exception? If so, lots of time will be saved.

**UPDATE**

How can I move this question to Programmers? It is off-topic here.

Comment: You are wrong about the purpose of exceptions if you think that you should put a `try`...`catch` around every single call. Exceptions are not used like return values.

Comment: Regretfully, C++ exception specification is not utterly useful.

Comment: @SergeyA: In this case, it is. All functions not declared `throw()` or `noexcept` may throw exceptions.

Comment: Exception specification is useful in Java. There, it is checked during compilation and violation of the spec is an error. Basically, every function has exception spec (emty by default) and no function can throw an exception unless it is listed in it's spec (nothrow is by default, than). It would check for direct throw(), as well is check exception specification of all functions you are calling. This is what I call useful specification.

Comment: @SergeyA: Not true. In Java, there are checked and unchecked exceptions. Unchecked exceptions are by far the more common and more important ones, `NullPointerException` being the most prominent example. You don't specify `throws NullPointerException` (or `IllegalArgumentException` etc) for Java methods for the same reasons that C++98 exception specifications have proven useless, except of `throw()` or its `noexcept` successor - which Java *cannot* express...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to write such a tool which will work with 100% accuracy, because any of your callback / virtual function call might be resolved at run-time (i.e. program decides which function to call from the potentially infinite list of functions based on it's input) and it might either throw exception or not. It is possible to treat all such calls as "potentially throwing" but in this case production use of such a tool will be quite questionable...

Comment: "Potentially throwing" is all you are ever really interested in. That's the whole purpose of `noexcept` and the reason why exception specifications have been deprecated in C++11.

Comment: @ChristianHackl When I'm surprised why there is no clang-based tool for that yet...